# DeletedRowInaccessibleException while doing for each

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I understand what the exception means, what I do not understand is why are the rows that are marked for deletion being picked up even when I mention a predicate `dataRow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted`
in my 'where' clause?

```
    //DataSet is a strongly typed dataset
    DataSet.TableB_row rowToDelete = dataSet.TableB.where(x=>x.ID==ID).First();
    rowToDelete.Delete(); 
    //don't want to use Remove(), might have to do RejectChanges depending on logic
    //I do not want to call AcceptChanges just yet.
    var results = (from rowA in dataSet.TableA
                   join rowB in dataSet.TableB
                        on rowA.ID equals rowB.ID
                   join rowC in dataSet.TableC
                        on rowB.ID equals rowC.ID
                    where rowB.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted
    //added RowState check for other tables hoping that might fix, but didn't
                        && rowA.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted
                        && rowC.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted
                        && rowA.ID == someID
                        select new { rowB.ColA, rowC.ColA });

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
       //deletedRowInaccessibleException thrown
       //some logic, not modifying the collection. Doesn't even get this far.
    }
```

Certainly I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out. Similar post on SO, mostly suggest adding RowState check, which I already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without accepting the changes, the **join** seems to try to evaluate the ID of the deleted row before filtering it out with **where** clause. To work around that, you could first create a "bRows" query and use that in the **join**, rather than using TableB directly. Something like this.

```
var bRows = dataset.TableB.Where(r => r.RowState != DataRowState.Delete);
var results = (from rowA in dataset.TableA
               join rowB in bRows
                    on rowA.ID equals rowB.ID
               join rowC in dataset.TableC
                    on rowB.ID equals rowC.ID
               select new { rowB.ColA, rowC.ColA });
```

Comment: Thanks man, your explanation showed me the way. I ended up doing from rowA in dataset.TableA
join rowB in bRows.Where(r => r.RowState != DataRowState.Delete) on rowA.ID equals rowB.ID. Besides that, I was not taking into consideration that when I do delete in TableB it deletes child rows from TableC as well. Thanks man!